# Where was the mistake

Tags: special-functions

we know that $$\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t}{e^t-1}dt$$, we also know that $\frac{t}{e^t-1}$ is the generating function for the Bernoulli numbers i.e $ \frac{t}{e^t-1} =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{B_nt^n}{n!}$. If we use this generating function in the above i.e $$\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{B_nt^n}{n!}dt$$ changing the order of integration $$\frac{\pi^2}{6}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^n}{n!}dt$$ but this is not true. Where is the flaw.

Comment: $\frac{t}{e^t-1}$ is an analytic function but not an entire one. The radius of convergence in the origin is $2\pi$.

Comment: but it has power series expansion, then the series is uniformly converges then, we can change the order of integration

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391807/radius-of-convergence-of-the-bernoulli-polynomial-generating-function-power-seri

Comment: Restating Jack's comment: The series doesn't even converge for $t\ge2\pi$. Before you can interchange the integral and series, it's a requirement that the series makes sense for all values in the integral's domain. The power series does not converge uniformly to the function on the interval $[0,\infty)$, it doesn't even converge at all on $[2\pi,\infty)$.

Comment: I got my mistake